# Need help trying to access data from parent relationship

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I'm tasked to retrieve data from an order payment line when a transaction happens on a related product and the field is_Enabled__c is marked true on the product, the product does not have a direct relationship with order payment line but it does have a relationship with Order Line which is related to the product.

How do I access the related product field from order payment line to check if that field is marked as true ?

I'm new to this kind of environment so sorry if I didn't formulate my question correctly.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your schema?

Comment: What is the closest direct ancestor to all of the fields in question? And what is the relationship to these descendants?

Comment: Hi @AbrahamLabkovsky, I have Order_Payment_Line__c with a lookup relationship to Order_Line__c, and Order_Line__c has a lookup relationship to Product__c, when an order payment line related to the product is inserted, I need to check if Is_Enabled field(which is a field on the product__c object) is marked as true.

Comment: When trying to traverse up a level, replace the `__c` with an `__r`. Have you tried `Order_Line__r.Product__r.is_Enabled__c` or something like that?

Comment: If it is something that is directly related like that, you can make a formula field on the lowest level, `Order_Payment_Line__c` that looks up this data. The formula builder tool should help you make the lookup.

Comment: You didn't outline in your question how you need this data. If it is in a report or a trigger or a Process Builder or something. Each of those should provide some method of doing what I outlined above...

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky sorry Abraham, it needs to be a trigger. I tried your solution of trying to traverse up a level with a query but on the query result I get "Object object" as a result on the Order_Line__r._product__r.isEnabled_c column instead of a boolean value, I also did it on the anonymous console and I it retrieved the and id instead of the actual field...

Comment: Can you post some code or something in your question? Its hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish